Blender baking so I can export object with material to unity showing up black



I am trying to bake a texture from blender into unity so that it works well. However, no matter what I try, the bake always shows up looking complete black with no color whatsoever. I have used Smart UV project for this, I have looked at every online tutorial and followed correctly but for some reason, the texture just keeps baking to complete black. My bake settings and the screen are shown above. Here are the exact steps I took based on various tutorials. I first created a single texture for my object. I did a UV smart project so it was unwrapped. I then created an empty image texture not connected to anything in that same material. I then went to cycles rendering tab, and went down to the bake settings, I set it to diffuse and unchecked the light options. Then I selected the mesh, the texture node, and hit bake and it was black

Hi. What happens if you set the Metallic value to anything less than 1?
